# How do i change the default highlight in word using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlighting

I am writing a sub that finds specific text by whole word and highlights it. The problem is that the user wants the text in grey (wdGrey25) rather than the default of yellow. Here is my sample code:

```
Public Sub HighlightStrings()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
    With rng.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWholeWord = True

        .Text = "Claimant's name"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "date"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "he/she"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "describe incident"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "describe condition(s)"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "describe occupational disease"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With

End Sub
```

So far, it works perfectly to find and highlight without throwing alignment and positioning off, as with previous versions, but the highlight color is too painful for our older users to look at. Anyone got a fix for that?

Thanks in advance,
-C§

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
   Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdGrey25
```

You need to set it at the beginning of your code.